# Web App lib jar deletion issue with STS

Tags: java, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using STS 3.1 and I am not able to delete the jar that is not used from either STS nor file system, unless i close the STS and delete from the file system.

The problem occurs once I start the web application. Then I cannot delete any jar even if I stop the server. I tried removing the WebApp Libraries from the classpath, but cannot delete the jar.

Is there any fix for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the bug with the eclipse.

Here is a similar problem filed as bug in eclipse site.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=101360

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because Windows locks files for deletion when they are opened by an application.  I don't know which application is locking it since it is not directly being used by STS or your server.  But, I am aware of [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/), which you can use to delete files locked by an application.